# What is the fastest way to generate all possible 6 length string and write to file?

Tags: java, performance

I would like to generate all possible 6 length strings
I need this format: 
aaa000
aaa001
...

Here is my code:

```
private List<String> licensePlateList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> letterList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    app.generateNumbers();
    int letters = 26;
    int count = 3;
    final int combinations = (int) Math.pow(letters, count);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < combinations; i++) {
        sb.setLength(0);
        for (int j = 0, i2 = i; j < count; j++, i2 /= letters)
            sb.insert(0, (char) ('a' + i2 % letters));
        app.letterList.add(sb.toString());
    }

    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to generate", time / 1e9);

    for (int i=0;i<app.letterList.size();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<app.numberList.size();j++){
            String licensePlate = app.letterList.get(i)+app.numberList.get(j);
            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("licensePlate2.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
            {
                out.println(licensePlate);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to generate %,d combinations%n", time / 1e9, app.licensePlateList.size());
}

private void generateNumbers(){
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        numberList.add(String.format("%03d", i));
    }
}
}
```

I generate all possible numbers in the generateNumbers() method. In the main() method after I  generate numbers I generate all possible 3 length strings into letterList.
After I map every string with numbers and write out to file.

But it's really slow. Do you know a faster way?

Comment: Why do you need to generate this list? If you need to generate the list because you need the list to do some other operation, why don't you just generate it slowly once and then hard-code the values into your program? That's probably about as "fast" as you can get.

Comment: I had an exam and that was the first task, and i had to work with its result. But my code didn't finish in 3 hours and now I would like to know what is the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is opening a new writer for every licence plate.

Instead, open one writer and write them all to that:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("licensePlate2.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
    for (String letters : app.letterList) {
        for (String numbers : app.numberList) {
            out.print(letters);
            out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note how this code avoids creating an intermediate string for the whole licence number by writing each string separately.

Note also the use of "for each" loops.

Comment: Thank you! With your code I generated every possible string in 13 seconds! This is really fast!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ java Test c:/temp/testOutput
Generated 17576000 combinations in 1.456 seconds
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char sb[] = new char[7];
        sb[6] = '\n';

        int count = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[0]));

        for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++) {
            sb[0] = a;
            for (char b = 'a'; b <= 'z'; b++) {
                sb[1] = b;
                for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
                    sb[2] = c;
                    for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; d++) {
                        sb[3] = d;
                        for (char e = '0'; e <= '9'; e++) {
                            sb[4] = e;
                            for (char f = '0'; f <= '9'; f++) {
                                sb[5] = f;
                                out.write(sb);
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        out.close();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println("Generated " + count + " combinations in " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Note that running the same code with /dev/null on Linux, NUL on Windows produces essentially the same time (.2 seconds less), so the disk IO cost is almost amortized out. The per-combination cost boils down to 1.456 / 17576000 = 0.082 microsecond. I am sure C++ could do better.

Update: changing BufferedWriter to BufferedOutputStream and replacing char[] with byte[] reduces the time to .908 seconds. This is because the writing code no longer needs to convert Java's UTF-16 encoding to UTF-8 used in the actual file.